# Can I disable mirrored weight paints in blender?

Tags: blender

Recently, I've been working on a 3D giraffe model in blender as a beginner and upon rigging the animal I have faced a problem.

In a nutshell I'll explain how I've done the model itself. Basically I followed 'Grand Abbitt's' youtube tutorial. I just drew the giraffe 'around' with a plane, made the plane 3D by extruding it and mirrored it to one of the axis so it becomes a 'whole giraffe' and I only have to edit one side.

Now, after parenting the mesh/model to the bones, I've realized that (obviously) the weight painting got mirrored too, and since the mirrored side is an 'illusionary' side, I can't edit it only the real, original side thus the original side's leg has a normal weight paint, thought its weight paint is mirrored to the other side thus the original side leg moves both legs, which I don't want to happen.

My question would be, is there any way - except for completely restarting the whole model - to just 'disable' weight paint mirroring/being able to weight paint the mirrored side?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too late for you at this point, but I found that if I selected the mirrored bone on the 'illusionary' side it would also have the bad weight painting, but on the real side, and I could remove that, and then it got mirrored and removed from the real side as well.